# Would I need to cite explanation of linux command lines?

Tags: citations

I am a bit confused about how I go about this, as the questions require me to search some commands and explain what they do, or in some cases the differences between the commands.

I've been trying to do that, but then I find that none of the actually knowledge ends up being mine. I'm just copying what others have said this command does, and what the differences between these two commands are, and possibly following it up with my own example.

I ended up with really just a reference after each one of my paragraphs.

Isn't there any way these commands and what they do could be considered common knowledge? In the end, many people are using them everyday and there are many websites explaining what they are for and how they differ from other commands. How would citation apply in this case?

Comment: Who is asking you the questions?

Comment: For "what they do", cite the man page (if that is where you get the information from), for "the differences" between commands - this sounds like something you should find out. If not, cite your source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common Linux commands can typically be listed without introduction, when you're writing for Linux users.<sup>1</sup> More advanced commands require introduction. As you've hinted, providing your own introduction is rather tiresome, because numerous introductions already exist. Hence,

- I suggest that you simply quote what others have said and provide a citation to the original.

Ideally, I'd recommend quoting `man` pages, since they are reputable, but you might have to rely on other sources when `man` pages provide insufficient detail.

---

<sub>1 What constitutes a *common Linux command* is rather vague. I'd certainly include `cat`, `cd`, and `cp`. I'd also include `less` and `more`. Thereafter I'd be a little hesitant, should `grep`, `ps`, ... be considered common?</sub>

Comment: There are so many guides to GREP floating around online that I'd argue it's certainly common enough to not have to really explain yourself.